# Deleting specific columns based on conditions

Tags: r

I have a dataset in R with a column indicating errors on a task: 0 = no error.  1 = error.

How do I delete the rows where the error column shows 1 (for error) AND the subsequent row (even if it is a 0) ?

Example:

```
  id part block response       time wrong
1  1    1     1      307 2015-04-26     0
2  2    1     1      291 2015-05-03     1
3  3    1     1      310 2015-05-10     0
```

How do I delete rows 2 and 3?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% filter(!(wrong == 1 | lag(wrong == 1, default = F)))
```

Comment: This is amazing!!!  Thank you so much!  I'll apologize for my ignorance, but how do I save that filtered dataset in order to further analyze it?

Comment: Glad it helped. Consider clicking the checkmark on the left if it answers your question. In order to save the result in a variable, you could do `df2 <- df %>% filter(!(wrong == 1 | lag(wrong == 1, default = F)))`, then simply recall `df2` when needed.

Comment: Consider it checked.  Thank you again!

Comment: Steven, I'd love your help with one final step in my dataset management!  My email address is colin.wallaceat@gmail.com.  I'd greatly appreciate your expertise in R.

Answer (score 0):

1. Start by making a sample dataset:

   ```
   df <- data.frame(id=1:10, error=sample(0:1, size = 10, replace = T, prob = c(0.7,0.3)))
   ```
2. Find the row numbers of rows flagging an error, and to subsequent lines,
   regardless of their error state.

   ```
   to_remove <- c(which(df$error == 1), which(df$error == 1)+1)
   ```
3. Make sure that the row number is not greater than the number of rows in the df.

   ```
   to_remove <- to_remove[!(to_remove>nrow(df))]
   ```
4. Remove the lines.

   ```
   df <- df[-to_remove,]
   ```